# C++ declaring variables with "E"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I found this example `float a = 35E5;` and tried to compile it and was successfully compiled. I found that E tells to compiler how much decimal zeros will be added to variable value.

Then I tried to assign a value to a variable like this

```
float a = 5.0, b = 5.5;
float c;
c = (a + b)E5;
```

and compiler reports an error:

[image: compiler errors]

Now, my question is: why it's not allowed to assign values to variables like 2nd example and like in 1th example is allowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `E` designates scientific notation, and is only valid to declare **literals**

> I found that E tells to compiler how much decimal zeros will be added to variable value.

No it doesn't. The syntax `aEb` means `a x 10^b`. This is not specific to C++, this is an accepted standard in mathematics to represent [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: Mind you, E is also used in _hexadecimal_ literals where it designates a digit with decimal value 14. It only designates scientific notation in _floating-point literals_, although that definition does lead to a minor chicken-and-egg problem: In `3E5` the E designates scientific notation because `3E5` is a floating point literal because it contains an E. (This is only a minor problem because C++ requires the `0x` prefix for hexadecimal numbers. Other languages may interpret `3E5` as the decimal number 997)